# Rails: validate unique friendship relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association
to make a friendship system.

```
#Friendship model
id | user_id | friend_id
```

The problem is

1. How can I make the combination of `user_id` and `friend_id` unique?
   prevent creating `user_id = 1, friend_id = 2` from `user_id = 2. friend_id = 1`
2. I find this model design is really bad. Can I model it to actually store the combine of 2 ids? Like `friendship_id_combination = [1, 2]`, and then validate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
validate :users_are_not_already_friends

def users_are_not_already_friends
  combinations = ["user_id = #{user_id} AND friend_id = #{friend_id}",
  "user_id = #{friend_id} AND friend_id = #{user_id}"]
  if User.where(combinations.join(' OR ')).exists?
    self.errors.add(:user_id, 'Already friends!')
  end
end
```

---

Update 2019:

Revised suggestion:

```
def users_are_not_already_friends
  if User.where(user_id: friend_id, friend_id: user_id).exist?
    || User.where(user_id: user_id, friend_id: friend_id).exist?
    self.errors.add(:user_id, 'Already friends!')
  end
end
```

And I would strongly advise to add a DB constraint (unique index) based on the composite `user_id` and `friend_id`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_user_id_friend_id_key ON users (user_id, friend_id);
```

Comment: I think this prevents creating two `user_id = 1, friend_id = 2`, rather than a `user_id = 1, friend_id = 2` and a `user_id = 2, friend_id = 1`.

Comment: What about  `if self.class.where(user_id: friend_id, friend_id:user_id).exist?` ?

Comment: You could do this but you would have to check the opposite too (with a `validates`). It could work but 2 SQL queries would be triggered instead of one. It's up to you

Comment: Stumbled on this today, great solution! BTW, nowadays you can improve it further by making the validation into a single query (in Rails 5+) with `.or`, like: `User.where(user_id: friend_id, friend_id: user_id).or(User.where(user_id: user_id, friend_id: friend_id)).exists?`. Also, for a 2-way index on the DB [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037484/3070597) looks the best option. Combining both is the ideal approach IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are thinking along the right path. Perhaps the simplest solution is to use the database table to create the validation by making the combination of IDs a unique index.

```
class CreateFriendshipsUnq < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :friendships, [:user_id, :friend_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

I think this will do what you want.

Comment: This will validate just one side, but not the inverse relationship

Answer (score -1):

Why you need this unique combination. Consider if you want to fetch friends of single user then in current scenario you can find it using simple association.

```
@user.friends
```

And if you don't want to add two keys then you need to fire two queries to find same details. One for your friends and other for who requested you as a friend.

Comment: Because in most cases, I want to fetch `@user.friends`, no matter who create the relationship, (whether user_id == @user, or whether friends== @user).