# Postgresql enforce unique two-way combination of columns

Tags: postgresql, unique, combinations

I'm trying to create a table that would enforce a unique combination of two columns of the same type - in both directions. E.g. this would be illegal:

```
col1 col2
   1    2
   2    1
```

I have come up with this, but it doesn't work:

```
database=> \d+ friend;
                                Table "public.friend"
    Column    |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 user_id_from | text                     | not null  | extended |              |
 user_id_to   | text                     | not null  | extended |              |
 status       | text                     | not null  | extended |              |
 sent         | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
 updated      | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "friend_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id_from, user_id_to)
    "friend_user_id_to_user_id_from_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id_to, user_id_from)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "friend_status_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES friend_status(name)
    "friend_user_id_from_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id_from) REFERENCES user_account(login)
    "friend_user_id_to_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id_to) REFERENCES user_account(login)
Has OIDs: no
```

Is it possible to write this without triggers or any advanced magic, using constraints only?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A variation on Neil's solution which doesn't need an extension is:

```
create table friendz (
  from_id int,
  to_id int
);

create unique index ifriendz on friendz(greatest(from_id,to_id), least(from_id,to_id));
```

Neil's solution lets you use an arbitrary number of columns though.

We're both relying on using expressions to build the index which is documented 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: Nice one dude. Very simple

Comment: Thank you. Could not find this anywhere.

Comment: How can I make this work with an upsert? The ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) form does not seems to work since this is an index.

Comment: For the ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING case, you don't need to specify anything. For the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE case, I think you don't need to give a column list (col1, col2) but you can specify the index name directly if I remember correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to do so with two columns of type `text`? Or would you need to go via the triggers approach?

Comment: @2pac - the least and greatest functions support character data types so will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Do you consider the intarray extension to be magic?

You'd need to use int keys for the users instead of text though...

Here's a possible solution:

```
create extension intarray;

create table friendz (
  from_id int,
  to_id int
);

create unique index on friendz ( sort( array[from_id, to_id ] ) );

insert into friendz values (1,2); -- good

insert into friendz values (2,1); -- bad
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c84b7/1