# Rails/PostgreSQL - How validates where there can only be one combination of two user ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, activerecord

I have a problem when I'm trying to create a Chat Join Table. There are two user_ids in it, user_id1 and user_id2. I can get the uniqueness validation of when user_id1 is 1 and user_id2 is 2; no more chats can be created with those exact attributes. But I'm performing a matchmaking search so sometimes the match comes up where the user_id1 is 2 and user_id2 is 1, which is a problem.

I've been searching for uniqueness constraints between those two on a database level, and I can't seem to find any. I think for the Model level I have to create a custom validation, which I can figure out, but is there a way to do this on the database level? Or is there a better way to approach this? Thanks in advance.

tl;dr:

a = 1, b = 2

I need a constraint on b = 1, a = 2.

Comment: I think this should work. In your model `validates :user_id1, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id2 }` and this in your migration `t.index [:user_id1, :user_id2], unique: true, name: 'index_user_id1_and_user_id2'`. The migration should add a uniqueness constraint to your table.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yea thats what I currently have. Right now it does add a constraint on the uniqueness of the pair, but not the combination in the pair. As in there can be no other user_id1: 1, user_id2: 2 pairs. But there still can be user_id1: 2, user_id2: 1 pairs, which is what I'm trying to constrain.

Comment: Didn't realize it only went 1 way (idX and idY) not the opposite too.  Can you add a second constraint in your migration? `t.index [:user_id2, :user_id1], unique: true, name: 'index_user_id2_and_user_id1'` then you'd have both?

Comment: The double indexing doesn't work it just adds individual constraints on both indexes. I'm not too comfortable but I'm willing to learn. I just figured it would have a simpler way to do it but I might be in the wrong.

Comment: One idea is to create another column with its value as a sorted array of  user_id1 and user_id2, and enforce uniqueness on that.

Answer (score 1):

The [usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037484/479863) to do this is to [create an index on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) and use the [`greatest` and `least`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) functions to build an expression that ignores the order of the columns. In your case, you want an index like this:

```
create unique index whatever_you_want_to_call_it
on your_table(greatest(user_id1, user_id2), least(user_id1, user_id2))
```

I'm not aware of any way to get ActiveRecord to construct such an index nor will it be stored in `schema.rb`. The work around for those problems is to switch to an SQL schema and manually create the index in a migration. To switch from `db/schema.rb` to `db/structure.sql`, update the settings in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

and then create the index in a migration:

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q{
    create unique index whatever_you_want_to_call_it
    on your_table(greatest(user_id1, user_id2), least(user_id1, user_id2))
  })
end
```

Then you can throw out your `db/schema.rb` (since it will no longer be used) and start working with `db/structure.sql` instead. You'll also want to start using different rake tasks:

- `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`
- `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`