# How can I use GREATEST and LEAST in a Rails migration?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to ensure bi-directional uniqueness within a table `friendships` on the columns `requester_id` and `accepter_id`.

```
Table: friendships

requester_id | accepter_id
--------------------------
           1 |           2
           2 |           1  <-- this should not be possible
```

As a solution to consider, I found this approach: [Postgresql enforce unique two-way combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036837/postgresql-enforce-unique-two-way-combination-of-columns#30037484)

```
create unique index ifriendz on friendz(greatest(from_id,to_id), least(from_id,to_id));
```

I am trying to write a Rails migration (I know I could use plain SQL as well but I would like to have it clean).

This is my attempt to rewrite the command. It does not work.

```
class AddBidirectionalUniqueConstraintToFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add index :friendships, greatest[:requester_id, :accepter_id], least[:requester_id, :accepter_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know a thing about Rails ActiveRecord, but if it be like most other ORM frameworks, then it is probably limited to mostly ANSI flavored SQL capability.  The `greatest` and `least` functions are very much database specific.  Postgres and MySQL support it, but not all databases.  So what you are trying to do may not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run arbitrary SQL commands using an `execute` command.

For example:

```
class AddBidirectionalUniqueConstraintToFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      create unique index ifriendz on friendz(greatest(from_id,to_id), least(from_id,to_id));
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      drop index ifriendz;
    SQL
  end
end
```

```

Comment: Thank you. Is this clean considering this might only be available with MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Comment: This isn't enough. `db/schema.rb` won't contain the proper index unless you also switch to `db/structure.sql`.

Comment: mu is correct, in your `config/application.rb` you will want to set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` to use `db/structure.sql`

Comment: I think you can do this with Rails code (without changing schema.rb to structure.sql) since they allow expression indexes. `add_index :ifriendz, "greatest(from_id,to_id), least(from_id,to_id)", name: "ifriendz_bidirectionally_unique_on_from_id_to_id", unique: true`. Source https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-adds-support-for-expression-indexes-for-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking how to prevent bi-directional uniqueness. Using GREATEST and LEAST is just one approach. Instead, you could write a custom validation:

```rb
class Friendship
  validate :bidirectional_uniqueness

  def bidirectional_uniqueness
    if Friendship.where(requester_id: accepter_id, accepter_id: requester_id).present?
      errors.add(:requester_id, "is not bidirectionally unique with accepter_id")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, I'm back at my own answer a month and a half later. I had two background jobs hit my model at roughly the same time, each build method passed validation, and then saved without error because I didn't have a database constraint. I am now implementing the database constraint. An alternative solution is sequence-based background jobs rather than concurrent.