# Django Enforce unique combination of pair of foreign keys

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-postgresql

So let's say I have the following Django models defined:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    model_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=true)
    content = models.TextField()

class ModelRelation(models.Model):
    relation_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=true)
    model_id1 = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_id2 = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With a regular UniqueConstraint in the constraints option of the Meta class,
a foreign key pair of model_id1 = 1 and model_id2 = 2 is allowed to coexist with
a foreign key pair of model_id1 = 2 and model_id2 = 1.

How do I implement a behaviour like in the first answer to [Postgresql enforce unique two-way combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036837/postgresql-enforce-unique-two-way-combination-of-columns) in Django?
How do you even make an unique index in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ManyToMany Field which is automatically symmetrical: [ManyToManyField Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Comment: This seems to solve my problem in another way, thanks