# Prevent 'duplicate' rows in a many to many table

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, many-to-many, hasura

In my project I have this feature where users can invite each other to connect.

My (postgres) database table structure (in Hasura) looks like this:

```
id // uuid
sender_id // uuid - user id
receiver_id // uuid - user id
status // enum - pending | declined | connected
```

Inserting rows into this table works perfectly but I'm looking for a way to prevent 'duplicate' rows.

In my feature it would technically be possible for users to invite each other at the same time.

The following rows would be 'duplicates'.

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | status
--------------------------------------
0    1234        6789          pending
1    6789        1234          pending
```

I was thinking about creating some kind of composite primary key out of concatinating the `sender_id` and `receiver_id` and use that in an upsert query. When this primary key would conflict then instead of adding a new row I would update the status to 'connected'.

But since the `sender_id` can be the `receiver_id` and vice versa I would never have a unique primary key.

Another thing I thought could work would be to sort the `sender_id` and `receiver_id` UUID's and store that as a primary key. By sorting I wouldn't matter which user is the sender or the receiver because the primary key would always be the same.

What would be the best/most common approach for this use case if I want to make this work with Hasura's `on_conflict` argument in a mutation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql enforce unique two-way combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036837/postgresql-enforce-unique-two-way-combination-of-columns)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I edited my question a few times so maybe you missed the part that I would like to use Hasura's `on_conflict` argument.

My current approach is to have an `id` (primary key) column that holds a sorted string based on the `sender_id` and `user_id` instead of having an `id` column that holds a UUID. The only downside is that I still cannot use the `on_conflict` argument because the value that I want to update the `pending` column with is not send with the mutation.

So I guess the solution to my problem requires more than one query.